# Django : How to link model one objects with model two in form?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I trying to link one model objects with other model in forms but ending up with invalid form

Models.py:
    class Patient(models.Model):

```
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200);
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20);
    address = models.TextField();
    Patient_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True);
    Gender= models.CharField(choices=GENDER,max_length=10)
    consultant = models.CharField(choices=CONSULTANT,max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

class Rooms(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    room_num = models.IntegerField()
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

class Ipd(models.Model):

    reason_admission = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
    presenting_complaints = models.CharField(max_length=200,)
    ipd_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    rooms = models.OneToOneField(Rooms,on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    blank=False)
    investigation = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    patient = models.ForeignKey(Patient,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null = 
    False)
```

Forms.py:

```
from .models import Patient,Ipd


class PatientForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = Patient
        fields = 
    ['name','phone','address','Patient_id','consultant','Gender']

class IpdForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Ipd

        fields = ['patient','reason_admission','presenting_complaints', 
        'rooms','investigation']
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def ipd (request,patient_id):
    patient = Patient.objects.get(pk=patient_id)
    if request.POST:

        data = dict(request.POST)
        data['patient']=Patient.Patient_id
        formtwo = IpdForm(request.POST)
        if  formtwo.is_valid():
            if formtwo.save():
                return redirect('/', messages.success(request, 'Patient is 
successfully updated.', 'alert-success'))

            else:
                return redirect('/', messages.error(request, 'Data is not 
saved', 'alert-danger'))
        else:
            return redirect('/', messages.error(request, 'Form is not 
valid', 'alert-danger'))
    else:
        formtwo = IpdForm(request.POST)
        return render(request, 'newipd.html', {'form2':formtwo 
,'form':patient})
```

i have Patient model that is used to create patient , and Ipd model which takes additional information from Patient before getiing admitted. so i am trying to link Ipd model with Patient to create New Ipd List

Answer (score 0):

first of all, this may not be the error, but it is a generally more accepted practice:
instead of

```
if request.POST:
```

do

```
if request.method == "POST":
```

Also, in your redirects, you are putting messages in the parameters. I am not sure about this but I think you might be able to do

```
messages.success ...
return redirect("/")
```

because I don't think that your redirect will work.
I have a strong suspicion that the error is after the else when you do

```
formtwo = IpdForm(request.POST)
```

because request.POST is already shown to be None
instead, do

```
formtwo = IpdForm()
```

Check out the [django form docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/).
Additionally, I am pretty sure that you cannot put a foreignkey in a form (in your case the IpdForm and the patient class). Instead, remove 'patient' from the form fields and do this

```
if formtwo.isvalid():
    formtwo.user_id = request.user.id
```

I hope this helps at least a little bit and you can figure out your problem